# Migrate C struct to Delphi record

Tags: c, delphi, data-structures, struct, record

I would like to know how to convert ***C struct to Delphi record***?

*The following code is in C. I want to convert to Delphi.*

```
typedef struct
  {
  Uint16        value1[32];
  Uint16        value2[22];
  Uint16        value3[8];    
  }MY_STRUCT_1;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Uint16 is equivalent to the Word type and the `[]` indicates an array.

```
MY_STRUCT_1 = record
  value1 : Array [0..31] of Word;
  value2 : Array [0..21] of Word;
  value3 : Array [0..7] of Word;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. It helps me a lot. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You might need to used the **packed** keyword.  Delphi, by default, will align variables based on (I believe) whether you're developing on a 16, 32 or 64 bit platform and what data types are within your record.  Using packed will change the length/size of memory required to hold the record.  C will pack the structure by default.

```
MY_STRUCT_1 = packed record
  value1 : Array [0..31] of Word;
  value2 : Array [0..21] of Word;
  value3 : Array [0..7] of Word;
end;
```

See also:
http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Packed

Comment: The above record does not require `packed` specifier. The modern Delphi versions use the same alignment rules as C/C++ compilers.

Comment: What about in Delphi 5? Does 'packed' still require to use?

Comment: As stated in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86), C structures aren't packed by default (compilers add padding).